# Line integral over a small length

Tags: vector-analysis, electromagnetism

In problem 4.7 of Griffiths' "*Introduction to electrodynamics, 4th Edition*", to find the potential energy of a dipole in an electric field $\vec{E}$ the following step is made:

> $$\lim_{\vec{d}\to 0} \,\, \int_{\vec{r}}^{\vec{r}+\vec{d}} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{x} = \vec{E} \cdot \vec{d}$$

Are there some more complete intermediate steps for this reasoning (I'm imagining something involving a first order Taylor expansion or similar, perhaps)? How can I show this step is valid for non-uniform $\vec{E}$-fields (or is it not)?

The last line in the image below is the step I am referring to.
[image]

Comment: It is true for fundamental calculus.  **Unless** it is across different media that requires boundary conditions.

Comment: @NgChungTak are there any intermediate steps that make it more obvious why it is true?

Comment: Using trapezoidal rule and mean value theorem (for integration).

Comment: @NgChungTak Thanks for your help so far, would you be able to show me?

Comment: Mean value theorem for integration

$$\int_a^{a+h} f(x) \, dx=hf(\xi)$$

for some $\xi \in (a,a+h)$.

Comment: @NgChungTak Bit embarrassed I didn't see this! And the mean value theorem for integration can be applied to line integrals because of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083108/mean-value-theorem-for-line-integral)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mean value theorem for integration**

$$\int_a^{a+h} f(x) \, dx=hf(\xi)$$

for some $\xi \in (a,a+h)$.